# Search a GridView to set PageIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView with a large number of rows.  I know how to search the GridView and filter the rows to only show rows that meet the search criteria.  I DO NOT want to filter any rows.  What I want to do is go to the PageIndex of the first row that meets the criteria, but still be able to click "Prev, Next", etc. from there.  I have been searching but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.  Surely, I'm not the only person trying to do this?

Comment: Have you tried something. It seems to me to be a simple matter of searching the source, get the index of the found item and calculate the page.

Comment: Presumably your grid view has a datasource. using linq you can do some magic `gridView.DataSource = YourDataSource.Select().Where(Function(r) DataSource.Rows.IndexOf(r) >= gridView.PageSize * gridView.PageIndex).CopyToDataTable()` at least that's what I'd do

Comment: @DanScott: Thank you!  I am basically looking for a starting point.  I have not used linq before, so I am unsure how to make your example fit my code.  My datasource is a SQLDatasource called `sdsContractsByContractNo` which is a stored procedure that takes parameters, `intCustomerID` and `strContractNo`.  The column in the dataset to search for is called `strContractItemNo`.